# Laravel 5.1 PHPexcel install error

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.1, phpexcel, maatwebsite-excel

I want to add class **PHPExcel** to my project. I use composer to add **PHPExcel**. I tried some command line.

```
php composer.phar update
```

or

```
php composer.phar require phpexcel/phpexcel
```

But, i alway receive error look like image:
[at here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1Sk5.png). And **maatwebsite/excel**, too.

What is wrong with my project? Please help me!

Comment: It should be `phpoffice/phpexcel`, not `phpexcel/phpexcel`

Comment: I will give it a go of you provide the content of composer.json file, at least require & require-dev.

Comment: @MarkBaker i try but still error look like image

Comment: @CalinBlaga i did it, but still error look like image

Comment: Please provide the content of composer.json file

Comment: @CalinBlaga composer.json file [at here](http://textuploader.com/5bg1w)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
"jrenton/laravel-scaffold": "dev-master"
```

and run composer update again.

jrenton/laravel-scaffold needs "fzaninotto/faker": "1.3.0", which I guess, was used in lower versions of Laravel

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved my project.

Answer (score 3):

First open the file composer.json 
and find require object/array and add line

```
"require": {
    "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0"
},
```

and composer update so composer update is completed
and open the file config/app.php
and find providers object/array and add line

```
'providers' => [
    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */

    'Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider'

 ],
```

and find aliases object/array and add line

```
'aliases' => [
      'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class

 ]
```

Comment: I did this, but still show error like image(attachment)